# Send an email when workbook is saved

Tags: vba, excel, save

I am trying to send an email that will update users of changes to a spread sheet.  I am trying to make it so that when the document is saved there will be an email automatically sent with a list of the changes.

Does anyone know if it is possible to automate email upon saving the document?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code here not fancy as Chip Pearson but easy to understand, This method also relies on using outlook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Outlook As Object, EMail As Object

Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set EMail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

With EMail
    .To = "EmailAddress1@Server.com; Email2@aol.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Put your subject here"
    .Body = "Add you E-Mail Message Here"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName ' To add active Workbook as attachment
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Test.xlsx" ' To add other files just use path, Excel files, pictures, documents pdf's ect.
    .Display   'or use .Send to skip preview
End With


Set EMail = Nothing

Set Outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

To set this up Here is the full guide:

First open up the VBA window using `ALT` + `F11` then Select Worbook on the window to the right, Then workbook from the drop down:

[image: Workbook]

Then from the Drop down on the right Select BeforeSave:

[image: BeforeSave]

Then paste your code there:

You should end with this:

[image: Final]

Comment: Does that last screenshot have a problem - the area where the code should be is blank?

Answer (score 1):

It should be. You'll need to place your code in the Workbook_BeforeSave event, so it is triggered when the workbook is saved.

Chip Pearson has a good article on [Sending E-mail from VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Email.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code in ThisWorkbook code section.  `Workbook_BeforeSave` event is triggered before workbook is save. Hope below code gives you an idea how it can be accomplished.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Identify here list of changes
    ' You can pass as a string to SendMail

    Dim strChanges As String
    strChanges = "test"

    SendMail strChanges

End Sub


Sub SendMail(msg As String)

    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim Flds As Variant


    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields

'Configure the below details

    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "test-002"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    With iMsg

        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = "test@gmail.com"
        .From = "test@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "msg" & " " & Date & " " & Time
        .TextBody = msg
        .Send
    End With

    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you provided gave me a "Compile error: Member allready exists in an object module from which this object module derives".  It is highlihgting the first line of code in the second section "Sub SendMail (msg As String)"

Comment: @DavidVanderVieren Move the `SendMail` procedure to Standard Module.