# Type Mismatch VBA cant be found

Tags: vba, excel

I have Finally got some working code but Im getting a "type mismatch" error once the Module2 function finishes and I have no idea why.

If I step through it, it steps through "End function" on module2 then I get a Type Mismatch, but it does send the email. Any help would be great

This VBA code is in 3 parts.

**1 Sub**

```
  Sub Workbook_open()

  Call Module1.GetData

  End Sub
```

**2 Module 1**

```
  Public EmailAddress As String
  Public CompanyNumber As String
  Public Name As String
  Public GroupComp As String

  Function GetData()

  Dim LastRow As String
  Dim rng As Range


  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

  For Each rng In Range("K2:K" + LastRow)

       If Not rng.Value = vbNullString Then
           Select Case rng.Value
               Case 1
                  Case Is = "True"
                    Let EmailAddress = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
                    Let CompanyNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Value
                    Let Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Value
                    Let GroupComp = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
                    Call Module2.Email(EmailAddress, CompanyNumber, Name, GroupsComp)
               Case 2
                  Case Is = "False"
           End Select

        End If
    Next
   End Function
```

**3 Module 2**

```
      Function Email()
     'MsgBox (EmailAddress)
     Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
     objMessage.Subject = "Stuffl " & (GroupComp)
     objMessage.From = "Department Name(Department@Email.com)"
     objMessage.Cc = "Department Name(Department@Email.com)"
     objMessage.To = (EmailAddress)
     MsgBox (EmailAddress)
     objMessage.TextBody = "TEST"

      objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
      ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

      objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
      ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "x.x.x.x"

      objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
      ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

      objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

      objMessage.Send

    End Function
```

Comment: In `Module1.GetData` you are calling `Module2.Email` with 4 arguments, but at its definition there are no arguments? Also, why use `Function` and not `Sub` instead? The functions you define will return `Variant` objects, is that necessary?

Comment: `Function Email()` why its a function if it does not return anything ? Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964917/send-an-email-when-workbook-is-saved/16965103#16965103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Function Email()` into

```
Function Email(emailaddress As String, companynumber As String, name As String, groupscomp As String)
```

You are not actually calling the Mail function , that's the problem i think

Comment: The Sub calls Module1 function, Module1 calls Module2 function. And it send the mail so it is calling it. But ill try the above none the less

Comment: that seems to have worked. can you explain to me why it worked please? I was passing the variables to the Mail function from the GetData function, i dont understand why I had to specify the variables again in the mail function.

Answer (score 1):

"i dont understand why I had to specify the variables again in the mail"

Whenever you pass values to a Sub or Function, you have to define that Sub or Function such that it is expecting to have values passed to it. So this won't work:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim i as Integer
    i = 5
    Call Bar(i)
End Sub

Sub Bar()
    i = i + 2
End Sub
```

Because Bar() isn't expecting to have anything passed to it. This will work:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim i as Integer
    i = 5
    Call Bar(i)
End Sub

Sub Bar(i as Integer)
    i = i + 2
End Sub
```

Because you have now told Bar to expect an integer to be passed to it.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation appreciated